# Bounty page is not loading when sorting by offered or earned

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

When click on view more in earned and offered  bounty section it give ***Not found*** error message

> [image]

same happen with the earned. It happens  when url have

`&sort=offered` or  `&sort=earned` param

but when do not have  those param, its working fine (`?tab=bounties` works fine)

Comment: Yep, happened to me too with earned bounties.

Comment: looking into this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in build rev. 2013.8.28.1386 (meta) / 2013.8.26.977 (sites)

Comment: Another localization victim?

Comment: surprisingly no